# How can I add an INDEX with Doctrine 2 to a column without making it a primary key?

Tags: mysql, indexing, doctrine-orm

I want to add an index to a table column in my MySQL database. I am using Doctrine 2 to create my database schemas.

I know that I can use

```php
/** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
```

to create primary keys. But my column shall neither have the `unique` nor the `primary key` attribute. It shall simply be an `index` in my table (MySQL knows these three types).

What is the proper statement to create such an index?

Comment: see past quesions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141309/doctrine-2-with-multiple-indexes

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you want to work with doctrine a table must have a primary key, see:

> Every entity class must have an identifier/primary key. You can select the field that serves as the identifier with the `@Id` annotation.
>
>  Reference: [Identifiers and Primary keys](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys)

To create an index: [Annotations Reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_index)

```php
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ecommerce_products",indexes={
 *     @Index(name="search_idx", columns={"name", "email"})
 * })
 */
class ECommerceProduct
{
}
```

Note that this is only being used if you generate the schema from your PHP code. So in case your table already exist you can also just add an index yourself.

Comment: Yeah thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I know that I have to use and that it's good practice to use primary keys. But I need other columns (others but the `id` that I want to put index on).

Comment: would be better if you can provide the actual answer here rather than a link

Comment: bad style without @ORM

Comment: this answer is outdated, please update with annotations

Comment: @Toskan please specify what exactly is outdated about the answer. Annotations are there.

Comment: sorry my bad, I meant attributes https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/attributes-reference.html

Answer (score 54):

When you use Doctrine and ORM:

```php
@ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="name_idx", columns={"name"})})
```

Answer (score 23):

With PHP8 attributes use `#[ORM\Index]`:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Index(columns: ['column_name'], name: 'columns_idx')]
class FooBar
{
    /* ... */

    #[ORM\Column]
    private bool $columnName = false;

    /* ... */
}
```

See: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/attributes-reference.html#attrref_index

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the complete example.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Symfony with doctrine, you will also need to `use` the `Index` class in order for the annotation to work properly

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Index;
```

Comment: Most people add a `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` then `@ORM\Index(...)`

Answer (score 8):

Part of working code

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CountryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(columns={"slug"})})
 */
class Country extends AbstractTrans implements SuggesterItem
```

Comment: result looks `CREATE INDEX IDX_5373C966989D9B62 ON country (slug);`