# How to get data from a column with this annotation @ORM\index

Tags: php, doctrine

Good afternoon, please tell me how to get the column data:

{@ORM\Index(name="localities_names_idx", columns={"name_ru", "name_cn", "name_en"})

I tried using queryBuilder :

```
$qb
    ->select('a')
    ->from(Locality::class, 'a')
    ->where('a.name_ru = :name_ru')
    ->andWhere('a.area is null')
    ->setParameter('name', 'Moscow');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

Without success

I need it for:

```
$em = $this->entityManager;
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('a')
    ->from(Locality::class, 'a')
    ->where('a.name_ru = :name_ru')
    ->andWhere('a.area is null')
    ->setParameter('name', 'Москва');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
$location = new Location();
$location->setLocality($result[0]['a_id']);
$location->setAddress($address);
$em->persist($location);
$em->flush();

return $location->getId();
```

Comment: You specify an index. You cant select an index. What is it that you want, could you add some examples?

Comment: Also, you've created a *combined* index. This only works when you do `name_ru=a AND name_cn=b AND name_en=c`. Im guessing you want multiple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141309/doctrine-2-with-multiple-indexes

Comment: I am use doctrine orm

Comment: Sorry but I'm having difficulties trying to understand what you're asking. Question title suggest you have problems with indexes (migrations failing to create it? DB server not using it for the query?). Question body asks how to retrieve data from the table. Code snippets seem to do some complex stuff involving two entities. All the information given is "doesn't work" (if it worked, I presume you wouldn't be asking). What do you want to do exactly and how does your current approach fail to work? Is your PHP setup configured to display error messages? Do you have a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: This turned into a review, but might as well keep it here

---

### You're using `index` wrong.

I'm guessing you're using it incorrectly. I'm assuming you want an index for faster search. However, the way you do now you've created a combined index. Example:

```
{@ORM\Index(name="thing_colour_idx", columns={"thing", "colour"})
Thing | Colour
--------------
Car    Blue
Car    Red
Bike   Green
Bike   Yellow
```

If you **always** (or at least *most of the time*) select by **both** columns, eg you **always** search for a BLUE+CAR, or a GREEN+BIKE, than this is the way to go.
However, if you to select all Thing=Car, *without* colour, then this index does nothing. You want this:

```
indexes={
    @ORM\Index(name="thing_idx", columns={"thing"}),
    @ORM\Index(name="colour_idx", columns={"colour"})
}
```

### You're not using `getResult` as intended

You do `->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR)`, but then follow it up with a `->setLocality($result[0]['a_id'])`. Unless you have performace issues, you dont work with IDs, thats a problem for Doctrine, not you. You should only care about objects:

```php
$locality = $em
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from(Locality::class, 'a')
    ->where('a.name_ru = :name_ru')
    ->andWhere('a.area is null')
    ->setParameter('name', 'Москва') // <- btw, this should be 'name_ru', same as two lines heigher
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();

$location = new Location();
$location->setLocality($locality);
```

### Dont use the querybuilder like that, use a repository

You're now placing service logic and query logic in one code. That is incorrect. An example of the way Symfony is intented:

```php
class LocalityRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Locality::class);
    }

    public function getLocalityByRuName(string $name): Locality 
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->where('a.name_ru = :name_ru')
            ->andWhere('a.area is null')
            ->setParameter('name_ru', $name);
            ->getQuery();
            ->getSingleResult();
    }
}

class YourService
{
    public function __construct(
        private LocalityRepository $localityRepository
    ){}

    public function somethingSomething()
    {
        $locality = $this->localityRepository->getLocalityByRuName('Москва');
        $location = new Location();
        $location->setLocality($locality);
    }
}
```

Final note: Try not to use a `->flush()` in a service. The job of a service is to do work, not to decide what to do it. A controller decides when something is done. Suppose you have another service which in which you alter things, but DONT want to flush them. You can now no longer use any service method that flushes.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that there were no name properties Ru

Comment: Good that you fixed it. I'd apreciate it of you'd look at my suggestion so it's not wasted time :)